# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error when running:

```
SELECT *
FROM   repsresidents rr 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM residents r1 
     INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT res_peopleidy AS peopleidy, 
                   min(res_id)   AS RES_ID2 
            FROM residents 
            WHERE  res_active = '1'
            GROUP  BY res_peopleidy) r2 ON r1.res_id = r2.res_id2) r ON rr.mainpeopleidy = r.res_peopleidy
WHERE  rr.communityidy = 1
```

I believe the problem is on `min(res_id) AS RES_ID2` because `res_id` is a PK.

Here's the schema of `residents` table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Residents](
    [RES_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RES_PeopleIDY] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RES_PhyMoveInDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_CurrentUnitNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RES_CommunityIDY] [int] NULL,
    [RES_DateStarted] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_NoPart] [int] NULL,
    [RES_LastUserUpdated] [int] NULL,
    [PER_ID] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_ID] [int] NULL,
    [LIF_ID] [int] NULL,
    [INT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TES_ID] [int] NULL,
    [STA_ID] [int] NULL,
    [STA_Type] [int] NULL,
    [NetworkSet] [int] NULL,
    [RES_Active] [int] NULL,
    [RES_HasImage] [int] NULL,
    [RES_UpdatedImage] [int] NULL,
    [RES_Bio] [text] NULL,
    [RES_BioUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_BioUpdateBy] [int] NULL,
    [ACT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RES_LobbyBio] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_LobbyBioUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_LobbyBioUpdateBy] [int] NULL,
    [RES_DiscNotes1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_DiscNotes2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_DiscNotes3] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_DiscNotes4] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_DiscNotes5] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RES_ExpiredDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_ExpiredUser] [int] NULL,
    [RES_FinishedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RES_TasksSet] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Residents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RES_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably the datatype of `repsresidents.mainpeopleidy` is `uniqueidentifier` but you have invalid data in the `varchar(50)` column in the other table.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes indeed mainpeopleidy is a uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS on Residents, I would have to believe that your issue is with RepsResidents. Any chance that mainpeopleidy is a uniqueidentifier?